# Woocommerce: How to check if coupon ever used by the user?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I create "text field" on woocommerce customer dashboard, that field is used to redeem coupon. Let say that i have coupon code "BIRTHDAY29" that i setup on woocommerce coupon to be used.

User input "BIRTHDAY29" on  my "text field", and hit button "REDEEM" so the transaction is applied programaticaly on their transaction history.

How do i know How many times a coupon "BIRTHDAY29" was used by that user? i want to check if "BIRTHDAY29" is ever used by that user or not, then i want to do "something.." if BIRTHDAY29 ever used by that user.

Hope you guys understand what i mean, thankyou!!

Comment: Do you care about customers who checkout without an account? "Users" have a user ID, but many stores do not require a customer to have a user account to checkout. I'm just asking, because the solution is much easier if customers are required to have an account and therefore a user ID exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function coupon_usage_for_customer( $coupon_code, $user_id = NULL, $email = NULL )
{
    $usage = 0;

    // There must either be a user ID or email address
    if( empty( $user_id ) && empty( $email ) )
        return FALSE;

    $params = [
        'limit' => -1,
        'type'  => 'shop_order'
    ];

    if( ! empty( $user_id ) ){
        $params['customer_id'] = $user_id;
    }

    else if( ! empty( $email ) ){
        $params['billing_email'] = $email;
    }

    // Get orders of customer
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $params );

    // Check if coupon used
    foreach( $orders as $order )
    {
        $coupons_used = $order->get_coupon_codes();

        if( 
            is_array( $coupons_used ) &&
            in_array( $coupon_code, $coupons_used ) 
        ){
            $usage++;
        }
    }

    return $usage;  
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_register_post_type', function(){
    $user_id = 12345;
    $email   = 'oneguy@example.com';
    $birthday29usage = coupon_usage_for_customer( 'BIRTHDAY29', $user_id, $email );
    if( ! $birthday29usage )
        echo 'The user has not birthday 29ed...';
});
```